# Cannot see images when using a CONSTANT path in XAMPP

Tags: php, html

I have setup a CONSTANT to define the images folder, but when I try to display the picture using the path I cannot see them.

I have checked permission and they are fine. I can include other files to that path so I know that it works.

```js
defined("DS") ? null : define("DS", DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR); 

define('SITE_ROOT', DS . 'Applications' . DS . 'XAMPP' . DS . 'xamppfiles' . DS . 'htdocs' . DS . 'images');
```

```html
<img src="<?php echo SITE_ROOT . DS . $product_image; ?>" alt="">
```

Comment: The path needs to be relative to your website's root directory, not your server's root directory. Try setting it  to `'/images/'`.

Comment: Believe it or not, MySQL couldn't care less about this specific issue. I've replaced the tag with HTML.

Comment: You mean set the CONSTANT to  define('SITE_ROOT', DS . 'Applications' . DS . 'XAMPP' . DS . 'xamppfiles' . DS . 'htdocs' . DS . '/images/');

Comment: No, `define('SITE_ROOT', '/images/');`

Comment: oh let me try that, thanks

Comment: So, to load images you would do, `<img src="<? echo SITE_PATH.'my-image.jpg' ?>">`.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen I know this seems very simple, but it still makes sense to create an answer to the question. Would you mind doing that? And ricosuave, after you see his answer, you can accept it by checking ✔ below the arrows on the left side.

Comment: @ricosuave If Sverri does not answer, yes! Please do that and click the check after you post it :)

Comment: Sure Armfoot I will accept it, I was just waiting for him.

Comment: Okay then, there you go :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path needs to be relative to your website's root directory, not your server's root directory:

```
define('SITE_ROOT', '/images/');
```